# Is Ext algebra of standard modules of quasihereditary algebras directed?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory

For a quasihereditary algebra $A$, we have a partially ordered set $\Lambda$ parameterizing the simples $L(\lambda)$/projectives indecomposables $P(\lambda)$.  It also parameterize a set of special modules called the standard modules $\Delta(\lambda)$ such that $\Delta(\lambda) \to P(\lambda)$ is a surjection such that the kernel has composition factors $L(\mu)$ with $\mu > \lambda$ and $\Delta(\lambda)$ has composition factors with $L(\mu)$, for $\mu\leq \lambda$.

Now let $\Delta = \oplus_{\lambda\in\Lambda} \Delta(\lambda)$.  Apparently, the following Ext-algebra: $\text{Ext}_A^\ast (\Delta,\Delta)$ is already known to be directed when $A$ is quasihereditary.  Does anyone know the reference for this result and proof?  Thanks.

Comment: The surjection is from P(&lambda;) to &Delta;(&lambda;) rather than the other way around.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything you need is written here

http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~sek/select/K-L.pdf

(see Lemma 3). I couldn't find the originial source, but it must be one of the references listed.

Let $B=\text{Ext}_A^\ast (\Delta,\Delta)$ with idempotents $e_i=\text{id}_{\Delta(i)}$. Then from Lemma 3 it follows that
$e_i B e_j \simeq \text{Ext}_A^\ast (\Delta(j),\Delta(i))=0$ for $i<j$ and also that
$e_i B e_i \cong k$. I suppose this is what you mean by the algebra being directed.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I am looking for.  I found the statement for $\mathrm{Ext}^1$ in Dlab-Ringel's "The module-theoretic approach to quasi-hereditary algebras" and thought the proof for all higher Ext should be similar, and this document is what I need.